# Condition rules in Promotion

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules, special-price

I wanted to add **BOGO (Buy one Get One Free)** promotion on my website. I have Successfully added it but **it is applied on same product only**.

Actually **my requirement** is like **if user purchases 2 products then one of them will be free** with condition that product with less than or equal to MRP will be considered as free across categories.

Comment: Hello sunny, what is your plan which among two will be the free one?